# Pivoting SQL table with crosstab function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I made this query that lists all real estate prices per m2 per year in a city. It works nice yet all years end up in rows, with the prices behind them. I would prefer seeing the years in columns with the price in a cell. Via stackoverflow I found the crosstab function and have experimented with it. Unfortunately I can't seem to make it work. Would love it if someone could have a look at the query.

Query output example

```
city        year    avg_price_m2
Amsterdam   2016    4407,51
Amsterdam   2017    5015,75
Amsterdam   2018    5648,1
Amsterdam   2019    5904,91
```

Desired

```
city        2016    2017      2018    2019
Amsterdam   4407,51 5015,75   5648,1  5904,91
```

Current query

```
SELECT city, 
       Extract(year FROM ondertekening_akte) AS year, 
       Round(Avg(transactieprijs_per_m2), 2) AS avg_price_m2 
FROM   transactiedata.transacties 
       JOIN bagactueel.gemeente 
         ON St_contains (bagactueel.gemeente.geovlak, 
            transactiedata.transacties.geopunt) 
WHERE  city = 'Amsterdam' 
       AND Extract(year FROM ondertekening_akte) > 2006 
GROUP  BY city, 
          year;
```

Pivot Attempt

```
select * from crosstab (
    $$select city,
    extract(year from ondertekening_akte) as year,
    ROUND(AVG(transactieprijs_per_m2),2) as avg_price_m2
    from transactiedata.transacties
    JOIN bagactueel.gemeente ON ST_Contains (bagactueel.gemeente.geovlak, transactiedata.transacties.geopunt)
    where city = 'Amsterdam'
    and extract(year from ondertekening_akte) > 2006
    group by city, year$$,

    $$select distinct extract(year from ondertekening_akte) as year from transactiedata.transacties order by year$$

)
AS (
    "city" text,
    "2007" int,
    "2008" int,
    "2009" int,
    "2010" int,
    "2011" int,
    "2012" int,
    "2013" int,
    "2014" int,
    "2015" int,
    "2016" int,
    "2017" int,
    "2018" int,
    "2019" int
)
;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid return type
DETAIL:  Query-specified return tuple has 14 columns but crosstab returns 17.
```

Comment: Don't do this in SQL, this is not what it was intended for. Do the transposing of rows to columns in your application when you display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query in `crosstab()` returns more than 13 rows (exactly 16). You should probably add the condition:

```
select distinct extract(year from ondertekening_akte) as year 
from transactiedata.transacties 
where extract(year from ondertekening_akte) > 2006 --!!
order by year
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks. Easiest way with what I had. "2007" INT had to be NUMERIC I found out as well.

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't designed for things like that, but if I really have to do it, I typically prefer conditional aggregation rather than trying to fight the `crosstab()` function:

```
select city,
       ROUND(AVG(transactieprijs_per_m2),2) filter (where extract(year from ondertekening_akte) = 2007) as "2007",
       ROUND(AVG(transactieprijs_per_m2),2) filter (where extract(year from ondertekening_akte) = 2008) as "2008",
       ROUND(AVG(transactieprijs_per_m2),2) filter (where extract(year from ondertekening_akte) = 2009) as "2009",
       ROUND(AVG(transactieprijs_per_m2),2) filter (where extract(year from ondertekening_akte) = 2010) as "2010",
       ... and so on ...
from transactiedata.transacties
   JOIN bagactueel.gemeente ON ST_Contains (bagactueel.gemeente.geovlak, transactiedata.transacties.geopunt)
where city = 'Amsterdam'
  and extract(year from ondertekening_akte) > 2006
group by city;
```

Answer (score -2):

I know how to PIVOT in SQL Server, but I'm pretty sure Crosstab and MSSQL share same syntax for PIVOT. Since I don't have any ways to test it, can you try this code?

```
    select City, [2011],[2012],[2013],[2014]
    from transactiedata.transacties
    JOIN bagactueel.gemeente ON ST_Contains (bagactueel.gemeente.geovlak, transactiedata.transacties.geopunt)
    where city = 'Amsterdam'
    and extract(year from ondertekening_akte) > 2006
PIVOT(ROUND(AVG(transactieprijs_per_m2),2)
     FOR YEAR IN ([2011],[2012],[2013],[2014])
```